# Why wont my UITextField save?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When my UITextView places a line of text into my first UITextField i cant save the text it holds.

Heres my code, this is to move the information from a textview

```
-(IBAction)print:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"text = %@",[textView text] );
NSArray *textArray = [[textView text] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];


if (textArray.count > 0) {
    NSString *line1 = textArray[0];
    [myTextField setText:line1];

    if (textArray.count > 1) {
        NSString *line2 = textArray[1];
        [myTextField1 setText:line2];
    }
}


[textView setText:@""];
[textView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Heres how i am currently trying to save and load the information.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[myTextField setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text"]];
[myTextField setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *defaultsKeyForTextField;

if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]) {

    defaultsKeyForTextField = @"textfield_text"; 

}
[defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:defaultsKeyForTextField];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

What seems to happen is that the text only saves when i enter in text manually.

Comment: `textFieldDidEndEditing` is only called when the textfield resigns first responder.

Comment: you should put breakpoints and debug the code, whenever you feel something is not going the way you want. you can use PO command to print a particular value in console as well.

Comment: why you are saving userdefault also in viewdidload ?

Comment: They aren't saving in `viewDidLoad`, they are retrieving the saved value.

Comment: i used logs and even with the code below it only seems to load whatever's been saved, but it doesn't save the text that comes from the textview.

Comment: @EICaptain yes and it seems its not being called.

Comment: @EICaptain Yes i just figured that out as well because i have an IBAction connected to it and every time i press it to load the textfields it saves an empty space. How can i change this then?

Comment: you mean to say when it loads another time it saves as blank ...

Comment: @EICaptain yes, thank you for understanding me.

Comment: @EICaptain so then what do i need to use to make it actually work correctly.

Comment: @EICaptain so what you mean is instead of using viewdidload use ViewWillAppear?

Comment: @vype ya if you are navigate to otherview and get back to this view ... it calls ViewWillAppear .. viewdidload not called always ... only once it loads .. but the thing is how and when you save your data into defaults ... thats the main thing ...

Comment: @EICaptain ahh that makes a lot of sense thank you. But the problem with saving still persists even when using viewdidappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [TangZijian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177871/why-wont-my-uitextfield-save#comment59990990_36177871) pointed out, `textFieldDidEndEditing` will be called when the textfield resigns first responder.

None of your code in `print` function do this.
Since set textfield as first responder and immediately resign it seems like a bad idea, you can move the code in `textFieldDidEndEditing` to `print`.

```
-(IBAction)print:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"text = %@",[textView text] );
    NSArray *textArray = [[textView text] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *defaultsKeyForTextField;

    if (textArray.count > 0) {
        NSString *line1 = textArray[0];
        [myTextField setText:line1];

        defaultsKeyForTextField = @"textfield_text";
        [defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:defaultsKeyForTextField];
        [defaults synchronize];

        if (textArray.count > 1) {
            NSString *line2 = textArray[1];
            [myTextField1 setText:line2];
        }
    }
    [textView setText:@""];
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: i actually tired that before and it never worked, but worked fine this time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a the Editing Changed event to detect changes to your text fields value. Put this in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
[myTextField addTarget:self 
          action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then change your code to:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaultsKeyForTextField;

    if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]) {

        defaultsKeyForTextField = @"textfield_text"; 

    }
    [defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:defaultsKeyForTextField];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Still no luck saving and loading.

Comment: i put in logs and it seems to be loading but not saving, and im guess it loads nothing.